# How to Put fields of an employee in accounting through a module? (ODOO 10)

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

Put fields of an employee in accounting through a module

Hi. I am creating a module for a client that has a specific need. He wants us to add a price per hour to employees. That is, the price charged by the employee each hour of work. Then create a small expense report that goes into accounting.

The first thing I have done is to modify the employee module using _inherit to add two fields. Nickname that allows employees to filter by nickname. And the hourly price of that employee (what this employee charges for every hour).

[employee example changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeHAh.png)

The second has been to create a new model that allows adding employees and importing said data. In addition to adding a description.

[form example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jp4NU.png)

The challenge now is to link this information to the accounting module so that it will appreciate as a Journal Item and then have the copy confirmed to be appreciated as a Journal Entries.

I am really new in the development of odoo and there are many things that I am still assimilating. So the questions I have are the following:

How could I do this?

Do I have a problem with what I have done so far?

It is my first post and I would appreciate the help. Thanks in advance.

This its the code:

```py
    class EmpleadoObra(models.Model):
       _inherit = 'hr.employee'
       apodo = fields.Char('apodo', readonly=False, store=True)
       precio_por_hora = fields.Float('Salario por hora', store=True)

       @api.model           
        def name_search(self, name='', args=None, operator='ilike', limit=100):
            args = args or []
            recs = self.browse()
            if name:
                recs = self.search(['|', ('apodo', 'ilike', name), ('name', operator, name) ] + args, limit=limit)
            return recs.name_get()



    class EmpleadosProductos(models.Model):
        _name = "employee.as.product"
        # _inherits = {'hr.employee' : 'empleado_id'}
        employee_line = fields.One2many(
            'employee.line', 
            'id', 
            string='Employee Lines'
            )

    class EmployeLine(models.Model):
        _name = 'employee.line'
        descripcion = fields.Text(string='Descripción', required=False)
        employee_id = fields.Many2one(
            'hr.employee', 
            string="Empleado",
            requiered=True,
            change_default=True
            )
        apodo = fields.Char('apodo', readonly=False)
        precio_por_hora = fields.Float('precio_por_hora')
        _rec_name = 'apodo'

        @api.onchange('employee_id')
            def onchange_employee_id(self):
                addr = {}
                if not self.employee_id.display_name:
                    return addr
                if not self.employee_id.apodo:
                    self.apodo = "no apodo"
                else:
                    self.apodo = self.employee_id.apodo
                    self.precio_por_hora = self.employee_id.precio_por_hora
                return addr
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. **Don't post images of code or error messages.** Read [why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: Thx im correct it!!